# Code-first auto-generated values not creating corresponding database logic

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I tried both attributes:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public Guid Id { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

And Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(b => b.CreatedDate).HasDefaultValue().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(b => b.LastUpdated).HasDefaultValue().ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(b => b.Id).HasDefaultValue().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

After migration and update, nothing happens in the database - I would expect a trigger or constraint here.

Reading through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties), it says:

> Database providers may automatically setup value generation for some property types, but others may require you to manually setup how the value is generated. For example, when using SQL Server, values will be automatically generated for GUID properties (using the SQL Server sequential GUID algorithm). However, if you specify that a DateTime property is generated on add, then you must setup a way for the values to be generated. One way to do this, is to configure a default value of GETDATE(), see Default Values.

Ok, but how then can I, using code-first, make the appropriate logic on the database. I don't want to create default values in my model, because then I would be dependent on going through my API. I thought the DatabaseGeneratedOption would do something.. right now it seems rather useless.

I saw some posts creating a trigger in the Up() method, but I don't really consider the migration folder to be a great place to put configuration code in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect a trigger or constraint here.

That's not what that configuration does, it instructs EF to reload the generated or updated value when saving an entity.

To achieve what you want, as also explained in that section, see [Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values):

> You can use the Fluent API to specify the default value for a property.
>
> ```
>   class MyContext : DbContext
>   {
>       public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
>
>       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>       {
>           modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
>               .Property(b => b.Rating)
>               .HasDefaultValue(3);
>       }
>   }
> ```
>
> You can also specify a SQL fragment that is used to calculate the default value.
>
> ```
>   class MyContext : DbContext
>   {
>       public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
>
>       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>       {
>           modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
>               .Property(b => b.Created)
>               .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
>       }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Thanks man, ok but would default value also cover computed value on update?

Comment: Ok think I found the answer here for computed values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/computed-columns